# Creating custom CRUD in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am following this tutorial: https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-US/training-courses/implementing-entity-framework-with-mvc-8931

But they completely skip over how to make the methods work for Find(), Remove(), and Dispose().  Typicallly when I scaffold these are automatically created, but in following this tut, they don't scaffold and leave out the part of creating the methods.

Here is the code I have in a repository, can someone lead me in the right direction to finding out how to do this?

```
     //Need to figure out how to create method for this.  
    internal Merchant Find(int? id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    //THis will be the Find method need to ask on Stack Overflow how to do this.
    //public Merchant Find( int id)
    //{
    //    return DbSet.Where(a => a.MerchantID.Equals(id));
    //}

    public System.Data.Entity.EntityState State { get; set; }

    internal void Remove(Merchant merchant)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    internal void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
internal Merchant Find(int? id)
{
    DbContext context = new DbContext();
    var Merchant  = context.Merchant.where(a=>a.Id.equals(id)).SingleOrDefault();
    return Merchant;
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

internal void Remove(Merchant merchant)
{
     DbContext context = new DbContext();
     context.Entry(merchant).State = State.Deleted;
     context.SaveChanges();
     throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Although you do not need to implement, but do not remove this from your class.

```
   internal void Dispose()
    {
       //You do not to implement it
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it!